# Navigation component drawer button click not working

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components

I am facing an issue with the button click of topmost link, it is not working, even though all configurations are set up the same way as others. Can anyone look and if they can find out the problem?

I have a menu link in the navigation drawer `R.id.nav_home` and it doesn't respond to the button click.

I have set all my fragments as top-level navigation to display sandwich icon everywhere. All links work except `nav_home` which is my `startDestination` also.

MainActivity

```
{
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_search_employee, R.id.nav_goods_issue, R.id.nav_issue_point,
            R.id.nav_goods_incoming, R.id.nav_brokenInitialFragment, R.id.nav_goodsBroken,
            R.id.nav_goodsBrokenPerson, R.id.nav_billing, R.id.nav_log_out, R.id.nav_sync,
            R.id.nav_issue_point_selection, R.id.nav_orders_completion, R.id.nav_orders_log_detail)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
}
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="@string/overview_team_leader" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_goods_issue"
        android:title="@string/output" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_issue_point"
        android:title="@string/delivery_and_return" />
.....
```

nav graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="de.eyescontact.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/overview_team_leader"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_registration"
            app:destination="@id/nav_search_employee" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_issue_article"
            app:destination="@id/nav_issue_point" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_return_article"
            app:destination="@id/nav_goods_incoming" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_issue_stock"
            app:destination="@id/nav_goods_issue" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_billing"
            app:destination="@id/nav_billing" />
    </fragment>

    <!-- check in and inner fragment -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_search_employee"
        android:name="de.eyescontact.ui.search.SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/all_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the id of the home fragment set in the navigation graph (`nav_home`) and that set in the drawer menu (`nav_home_fragment`). They must be the same in order to make the navigation works correctly.

[As per documentation:](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)

> If the id of the MenuItem matches the id of the destination, the NavController can then navigate to that destination.

Comment: I tried renaming, still the issue exist. Infact the names were same, i tried with renaming to see if it helps. Both names are same now and other links are working except this one, which is pretty weird.

Comment: Don't see anything else in your code ..it looks Ok to me. Not sure how to reproduce theis issue to help you out